# Using Microsoft Graph Client Sdk is it possible to alter or modify the reply subject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph Client Sdk is it possible to alter or modify the reply subject.

Currently I am only able to reply using a string which becomes the content body of the reply message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to do this in three parts:

1. Create a new reply
2. Update the message with your new content
3. Post the response message

Here's a sample of how to do this in the SDK:

```
var replyMessage = await graphClient.Me.Messages[message.Id].CreateReply().Request().PostAsync();

var newReplyBody = new ItemBody();
newReplyBody.Content = "Response" + replyMessage.Body.Content;

replyMessage.Body = newReplyBody;
replyMessage.Subject = "New Subject";
await graphClient.Me.Messages[replyMessage.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(replyMessage);

await graphClient.Me.Messages[replyMessage.Id].Send().Request().PostAsync();
```

Comment: thank you! but now I get an error stating "Microsoft graph api Write requests (excluding DELETE) must contain the Content-Type header declaration"

Comment: Can you post the code that is giving you that error?

Comment: Figured it out... i was passing a null value for the reply Id. Thanks again.

Comment: One more thing.. Is the draft message Id and sent message Id different?, if so is there a way to get the sent Email Id.